# Why do the packages in Synaptic Package Manager sometimes different from Ubuntu Software Updater?

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

There are times after running Ubuntu 18.04 Software Updater and I get the message “The software on this computer is up to date”.  However, when I run Synaptic Package Manager there are several more packages to update.  Also, is there anything wrong keeping both  Ubuntu Software Updater and  Synaptic Package Manager up to date?

What is the best way to provide example?  I can take a screen shot of the updater and terminal window.  It happened to me today prior to reading this post with the libsane package.  The Software Updater did not show an update was required, but SPM and the command "apt list --upgradable" did.

Obviously I can not run software updater at the sane time as Synaptic Package Manager. But, the screenshot should provide an example of the software updater indicating the system is up to date but the apt command and SPM indicate additional packages require updating.. See i.imgtc.ws/ihH7VPX.jpg

Comment: Can you give a specific example for this? They're both operating on the same backend, the package manager `apt`. So my only explanation would be that there was an update published between running one and the other. Unless you can reproduce the issue, I think there's nothing else we can say about it. Generally, when in doubt, check on the command-line with e.g. `apt list --upgradable`.

Comment: You should be using the Software Updater, not Synaptic, to manage updates, because Synaptic has some shortcomings that Software Updater (aka Update Manager) doesn't have.

Comment: Obviously I can not run software updater at the sane time as Synaptic Package Manager.  But, the screenshot should provide an example of the software updater indicating the system is up to date but the apt command and SPM indicate additional packages require updating..  See https://i.imgtc.ws/ihH7VPX.jpg

Comment: @ByteCommander  I have provided a specific example as requested.  Just trying to understand the difference between the two upgrade methods.